# Is there a Macbook (or pro) with TB3 USB C ports without butterfly keys

Tags: macbook-pro, dock

I wanted to get an older, pre-butterfly keyboard but I also really wanted TB3 support so I can connect my monitor, peripherals, etc. into a dock and then only have to connect a single USB C cable when I'm using the system at my desk.

Comment: Yes, the new MacBook Pro 16-inch. For the time being no other MacBook (or pro/air) of recent vintage has the scissors keyboard. I think the last one with the scissors keyboard were the 2015 MB Pro but no TB3/USB C ports.

Comment: Thanks. That's what I was afraid of. I thought the switch to TB3 typically came with the corresponding switch to the butterfly keyboard, but I was hoping that there may have been a couple exceptions to the rule out there.

Answer (score 1):

The 2019 MacBook Pro 16-inch computer does not have butterfly keys and includes Thunderbolt 3 USB-C ports. There is currently no other model, older or recent, that meets these criteria.